# Rails after_find callback usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Im trying to use the call back `after_find` in my model, I'm having issues trying to get it to actually update the rows that it found in the `after_find` method. It's throwing a no method error

**error**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 299ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <div id="hashtags" class="twitter-hashtag-voting-block-v1">
    2: <% @random_hashtag_pull.each do |hashtag| %>
    3: <div class="span4 twitter-spans-v1" id="<%= hashtag.id %>">
    4:      <div id="tweet-block-v1" class="hashtag-tweet-database-container">
    5:      <div class="tweet-block-border-v1">
  app/models/hashtag.rb:46:in `update_view_count'
  app/views/shared/_vote_tweets.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_shared__vote_tweets_html_erb__2738953379660121418_70243350609340'
  app/views/hashtags/create.js.erb:2:in `_app_views_hashtags_create_js_erb___1440072038737667206_70243345272440'
  app/controllers/hashtags_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

**hashtag_controller**

```
class HashtagsController < ApplicationController
  def home 
  end
  def vote
    @random_hashtags = Hashtag.order("RANDOM()").limit(4)
  end
  def show
  end
  def index
  end
  def create 
    Hashtag.pull_hashtag(params[:hashtag])
    @random_hashtag_pull = Hashtag.random_hashtags_pull
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to vote_path }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**hashtag.rb**

```
class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :text, :profile_image_url, :from_user, :created_at, :tweet_id, :hashtag, :from_user_name, :view_count

after_find :update_view_count

def self.pull_hashtag(hashtag)
  dash = "#"
  @hashtag_scrubbed = [dash, hashtag].join
  Twitter.search("%#{@hashtag_scrubbed}", :lang => "en", :count => 100, :result_type => "mixed").results.map do |tweet|
    unless exists?(tweet_id: tweet.id)
      create!(
        tweet_id: tweet.id,
        text: tweet.text,
        profile_image_url: tweet.user.profile_image_url,
        from_user: tweet.from_user,
        from_user_name: tweet.user.name, 
        created_at: tweet.created_at,
        hashtag: @hashtag_scrubbed
      ) 
      end       
    end
  end

  def self.random_hashtags_pull
    Hashtag.where{ |hashtag| hashtag.hashtag =~ @hashtag_scrubbed}.order{"RANDOM()"}.limit(4)
  end

  def update_view_count
    count = (view_count + 1)
    view_count = count
    save!
  end

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems here, one you know about and one you probably don't know about.

The first problem is that `view_count` has no default value so it starts out as `nil`. So the first time you try to update the `view_count`, you end up doing:

```
count = nil + 1
```

and `nil` doesn't know what `+` means. Calling `nil.to_i` gives you zero so you can do this:

```
count = view_count.to_i + 1
```

The other problem is that you have a race condition. If two processes end up viewing the same thing at the same time then you can end up with this sequence of events:

1. Process one (**P1**) pulls `view_count` out of the database.
2. Process two (**P2**) pulls `view_count` out of the database.
3. **P1** sends `view_count+1` back into the database.
4. **P2** sends `view_count+1` back into the database but it won't include the increment from **3**.

The easiest way to solve this is to use [`increment_counter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html#method-i-increment_counter):

```
def update_view_count
  Hashtag.increment_counter(:view_count, self.id)
end
```

That will do a direct

```
update hashtags set view_count = coalesce(view_count, 0) + 1
```

in the database so the race condition goes away as does the `nil` problem. You could also include a [`reload`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-reload) if you wanted to have an up-to-date `view_count` or just add one and don't save the modified Hashtag:

```
def update_view_count
  Hashtag.increment_counter(:view_count, self.id)
  self.reload
end
# or
def update_view_count
  Hashtag.increment_counter(:view_count, self.id)
  self.view_count += 1 # And don't save it or you'll overwrite the "safe" value!
end
```

The first one (with `self.reload`) will cause problems when tied to an `after_find` callback: the `self.reload` will probably trigger the `after_find` callback which will trigger another `self.reload` which will trigger the callback ... until Ruby starts getting upset about infinite recursion. But, it should work fine if you manually call `update_view_count` rather than tying it to a callback (see below).

The `self.view_count += 1` version can leave out some increments but that's probably not a big deal as you'll always have room for missing increments (unless you have live-updating on the view counts of course).

I don't think using a callback is a good idea for this sort of thing though. There will be times when you load a `Hashtag` out of the database but you don't want the `view_count` to increment. You'd be better off requiring an explicit method call to increment the counter, that way you won't increment things accidentally. Requiring an explicit call would allow you to use the first version (with `self.reload`) of `update_view_count` above as you wouldn't have the callback triggering the infinite recursion.

Comment: The first one ended up with a Stack too deep error and updated about +250 times, the second one works great.  I like the idea of getting the real value as well. 

I understand the thought behind not setting a callback.  

I tried doing something of the sort but the only way I knew the row id ended up was in the view and I didn't know how to pass that back into the method to run an increment.

Comment: @thebusiness11: Right, of course the `self.reload` would have recursion problems, that probably triggers the callback which triggers `reload` which triggers the callback which ... I'll add an update about that.

Comment: Would I then call the update_view_count inside of the def self.random_hashtags_pull ?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a good place for it. You could probably just tack an `.each(&:update_view_count)` on the end since `each` should return whatever it was iterating over.

Comment: Awesome, using `.each(&:update_view_count)` allowed me to remove the after_find call.  Thanks

Comment: And let this be a lesson to us all about how many sharp edges `after_find` has :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def update_view_count
  count = ( view_count || 0 ) + 1
  view_count = count
  save!
end
```

or maybe even this:

```
def update_view_count
  update_attribute :view_count , ( view_count || 0 ) + 1
end
```

The reason for the error is that there was no value (nil), hence the error trying to add to it. What the `||` operator does is tries the expression on the left, first, and returns that, unless it is `nil` or `false`. If it is `nil` or `false`, it will return the value on the right, even if it is `nil` or `false`. You can also do the same for assignment, like so:

```
false || true # returns true
nil || 'asdf' # returns asdf
false || nil # returns nil
aaa ||= 1 # assigns 1 to aaa, unless aaa has a value
```

As you discovered, a similar effect can be achieved by setting a default value, to prevent the `nil`.

Comment: So the second one worked when there was no default value set for view_count, but it would never update past 1.

If I set the default view count at 0 and then used

`def update_view_count
  update_attribute :view_count , view_count + 1
end` 

It worked as desired.  What was the || 0 +  action doing?  Am I using anything by dropping it?

Comment: I adjusted the code to allow it to increment past 1 (I forgot the parenthesis, it's late, sorry), and added some clarification regarding the `||` operator.